# Code doesn't continue with rest of code after tkinter button has been pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a code where I need to choose a certain number at the beginning. I do this with a tkinter button. The problem is after I press the button and choose the number the code doesn't continue.

Do I need to add something like `continue()`

```
parent = tk.Tk(className = 'choose number')           
frame = tk.Frame(parent, width=300, height=300)            
frame.pack()

button_step1= tk.Button(frame, text="0.0025", command=step1, height=2, width=10)    
button_step1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)                                                     

button_step2= tk.Button(frame, text="0.005", command=step2, height=2, width=10)
button_step2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

button_step4= tk.Button(frame, text="EXIT", fg="red", command=lambda: parent.destroy(), height=2, width=10)
button_step4.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

button_step3= tk.Button(frame, text="0.01", command=step3, height=2, width=10)
button_step3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

frame.mainloop()
```

step1, step2 and step3 all look the same but with different numbers for the variables.

```
def step1():                       
    global n_average 
    n_average = 80                                                              
    global n_rotate 
    n_rotate = 800                                                              
    global STEP_SIZE 
    STEP_SIZE = 0.0025
    parent.destroy()
    return n_average, n_rotate, STEP_SIZE
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. `parent.destroy()` will destroy your window... so what kind of behavior do you expect exactly?

Comment: I thought it would just close the window but remember the chosen button. But even if I delete that line it doesn't continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: If I use `parent.quit()` instead of `parent.destroy()` it continues, but the windows stay open which I don't really want. I tried to use `parent.destroy()` after `frame.mainloop()` but that doesn`t seem to work aswell.

Comment: Are you aware of the `withdraw()` method that allows you to hide the window from the user?